# Node.js Express won't serve absolute URL .js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have two files in /public/widget, help.html and help.js

```
http://localhost:8084/widget/help.html
```

in the *address bar* works fine

but

```
http://localhost:8084/widget/help.js
```

is not served ('Cannot GET'), even though my express use config:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(application_root, 'public')));
```

Any js inside an html file with relative path is served fine. (ie, if I use

```
  <script src="/widget/help.js"></script>
```

life is good; but

```
  <Script src="http://localhost:8084/widget/help.js"></script>
```

is not served. (I need the absolute url for referencing the .js in remote pages)

Here is my full Express config:

```
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
//checks request.body for HTTP method overrides
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'))    //checks request.body for HTTP method overrides
//Where to serve static content
app.use(express.static(path.join(application_root, 'public')));
```

I must be doing something dumb! Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "ignored/not recognized?" You get a 404 or what? Are you going directly to `http://localhost:8084/widget/help.js` in your address bar or are you instead referencing `help.js` from `help.html` with a `<script>` tag? If it's the latter, maybe your `src` path isn't correct?

Comment: Your problem is hidden elsewhere, I trust in you!

Comment: Maybe add a short description as to where your help.html and help.js is located in your directories?

Comment: We might need to see more of your app.js

Comment: What's the path stored in `application_root`?

Comment: `var application_root=__dirname`

Comment: It's something about this particular .js file... something incredibly stupid. Will report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with express.

"I need the absolute url for referencing the .js in remote pages".

So you have some remote system trying to load a file from your localhost.  Yeah, that won't work.  "localhost" on the remote system is not the same as "localhost" on your machine.  You need to give the remote system your IP address (or a domain name mapped to that IP) rather than a localhost URL.

Comment: In my dev environment, they are both localhost. One is localhost:8080 and the other is localhost:8084. You are right, something like this is happening. When I access the fully-qualified path within same host, it works fine.